# Swift get error when addConstraints for a UITextField with Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, visual-format-language

I want to add an UITextField into an UITableCell and set both it's width and height 100%;

My swift code :

```
nameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

addSubview( nameTextField )    

let views = [
    "name" : nameTextField
];

let widthLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "H:|-[name]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views )
nameTextField.addConstraints( widthLayoutConstraint )
let heightLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "V:|-[name]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views )
nameTextField.addConstraints( heightLayoutConstraint )
```

I got the follow error message while the table will show:

```
2016-07-31 19:16:43.027 NOIB[40193:1889520] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffbfa70f480 UITextField:0x7ffbfa41dff0.leading == NOIB.NameCell:0x7ffbfa41da10'NameCell'.leadingMargin> view:<UITextField: 0x7ffbfa41dff0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffbfa41e5c0>>'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that you are calling `addSubview` without specifying a view.  Usually it is used like:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(nameTextField)
```

Since you aren't specifying a view, then it must be using `self`.

Two views are involved in the constraints that are returned by your VFL:  your `nameTextField` and its superview.  In VFL, `"|"` represents the superview so it doesn't have to be explicitly included in the `view` dictionary that you pass in.  You need to add the constraints to the view that is higher in the hierarchy.  In your case, you need to add the constraints to the superview of `nameTextField`, which is `self`.  So you could probably do:

```
self.addConstraints(widthLayoutConstraint)
self.addConstraints(heightLayoutConstraint)
```

As of iOS 8, there is an easier way.  The constraints know which views they need to be added to, so you just have to set their `active` properties to `true`.  VFL can return multiple constraints, so you need to make all of them active.  You can use the class method `activateConstraints` of `NSLayoutConstraint` to activate multiple constraints:

```
let widthLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "H:|-[name]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views )
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(widthLayoutConstraint)
let heightLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "V:|-[name]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views )
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(heightLayoutConstraint)
```